# Uber eats integration with laravel and mysql, how to save json post data like mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm developing the integration of my software with Uber Eats api. I'm at the stage where they need to make a post on my webhook address. The data contained in json is below, but I need to write to the database in a way that interprets the target array as normal fields

JSON POST data from Uber Eats

```
{
"event_id": "c4d2261e-2779-4eb6-beb0-cb41235c751e",
"event_time": 1427343990,
"event_type": "orders.notification",
"meta": {
    "user_id": "89dd9741-66b5-4bb4-b216-a813f3b21b4f",
    "resource_id": "153dd7f1-339d-4619-940c-418943c14636",
    "status": "pos",
},
"resource_href": "https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/orders/153dd7f1-339d-4619-940c-418943c14636"}
```

My MYSQL table

```
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`event_id` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`event_time` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`event_type` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`meta.user_id` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`meta.resource_id` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`meta.status` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`resource_href` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

My Laravel Model

```
class webhook extends Model
{

public $table = 'tab_webhook_eats';

public $timestamps = false;

public $incrementing = false;

protected $primaryKey = 'ID';

public $fillable = [
    'ID',
    'event_id',
    'event_time',
    'event_type',
    'meta.user_id',
    'meta.resource_id',
    'meta.status',
    'resource_href'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'ID' => 'integer',
    'event_id' => 'string',
    'event_time' => 'string',
    'event_type' => 'string',
    'meta.user_id' => 'string',
    'meta.resource_id' => 'string',
    'meta.status' => 'string',
    'resource_href' => 'string'
];

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $rules = [

];}
```

My API Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Requests\API\CreatewebhookAPIRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\API\UpdatewebhookAPIRequest;
use App\Models\webhook;
use App\Repositories\webhookRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use InfyOm\Generator\Criteria\LimitOffsetCriteria;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use Response;

/**
 * Class webhookController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\API
 */

class webhookAPIController extends AppBaseController
{
/** @var  webhookRepository */
private $webhookRepository;

public function __construct(webhookRepository $webhookRepo)
{
    $this->webhookRepository = $webhookRepo;
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the webhook.
 * GET|HEAD /webhooks
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->webhookRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
    $this->webhookRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
    $webhooks = $this->webhookRepository->all();

    return $this->sendResponse($webhooks->toArray(), 'Webhooks retrieved successfully');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created webhook in storage.
 * POST /webhooks
 *
 * @param CreatewebhookAPIRequest $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(CreatewebhookAPIRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $webhooks = $this->webhookRepository->create($input);

    return $this->sendResponse($webhooks->toArray(), 'Webhook saved successfully');
}

/**
 * Display the specified webhook.
 * GET|HEAD /webhooks/{id}
 *
 * @param  int $id
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    /** @var webhook $webhook */
    $webhook = $this->webhookRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($webhook)) {
        return $this->sendError('Webhook not found');
    }

    return $this->sendResponse($webhook->toArray(), 'Webhook retrieved successfully');
}

/**
 * Update the specified webhook in storage.
 * PUT/PATCH /webhooks/{id}
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @param UpdatewebhookAPIRequest $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id, UpdatewebhookAPIRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    /** @var webhook $webhook */
    $webhook = $this->webhookRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($webhook)) {
        return $this->sendError('Webhook not found');
    }

    $webhook = $this->webhookRepository->update($input, $id);

    return $this->sendResponse($webhook->toArray(), 'webhook updated successfully');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified webhook from storage.
 * DELETE /webhooks/{id}
 *
 * @param  int $id
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    /** @var webhook $webhook */
    $webhook = $this->webhookRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($webhook)) {
        return $this->sendError('Webhook not found');
    }

    $webhook->delete();

    return $this->sendResponse($id, 'Webhook deleted successfully');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your implementation needs, but if you need a function to dynamically save model from json you provided, check if below helps :

Add this in Webhook model :

```
<?php 


/**
 * Create new model from array
 * 
 * @param  array $data
 * @param  string $previousKey
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function createFromAPIData($data, $previousKey = null)
{


    if(count($array) == 0){

        return $this;
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){

            $this->save();
            return $this->createFromAPIData($value, $key);
        }

        if($previousKey){

            $this->{$previousKey . '.' . $key} = $value;
        }
        else{
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->save();

    return $this;
}
```

Then in your controller you can do this :

```
<?php 

$json = <<<json

{
"event_id": "c4d2261e-2779-4eb6-beb0-cb41235c751e",
"event_time": 1427343990,
"event_type": "orders.notification",
"meta": {
    "user_id": "89dd9741-66b5-4bb4-b216-a813f3b21b4f",
    "resource_id": "153dd7f1-339d-4619-940c-418943c14636",
    "status": "pos",
},
"resource_href": "https://api.uber.com/v1/eats/orders/153dd7f1-339d-4619-940c-418943c14636"}

json;

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$webhook = (new Webhook)->createFromAPIData($data);
```

Note that this is just to give you an idea, you can use repository if you have it or other way to place this function

Comment: the need is that the json format is like this, it contains an array. in POST, the array data is not written to db.

I was a bit confused when implementing the code in controller, did you set $json with the template I posted?